# web services failed

Tags: web-services, wcf

I have created a web service (.svc). The web service is running successfully when i connect through local computer, but when i deploy the web serivce on a web server it can't be accessed and shows an exception.

"***Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine 'XXX' failed. Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. See help for more information.***"

The service is running in a browser successfully, and can also be accessed as a client from the web server in a broswer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a permissions related issue.

When you run locally, chances are that you have sufficient privileges to access the service.

The picture changes on the server. Check under which account the service is running then make sure you have the proper permissions or configure your service to accept calls from you or from unauthenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to debug the webservice on the server. Is that what you intended? Then make sure your account has rights to do so on the server.

[Debugging aspnetwebservice on a remoteserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291236(VS.71).aspx#vxtskdebuggingaspnetwebservicedebuggingawebserviceonaremoteserver)

If you want to make sure the webservice runs you also can open the webservice using a browser.

Comment: First of all thanks of you interest.

my web services are runing in browser successfully. butt when i connect through programatically (c#.net windows base app.) it show exception.